# Python - Pandas dataframe - iteration through a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, increment

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to add an empty column (named `nb_trades`). Then I would like to fill this new column with a 5 by 5 increment. So I should get a column with values 5 10 15 20 ...

Doing the below code assign the same value (last value of `i`) in the whole column and that's not what I wanted:

```
big_df["nb_trade"]='0'
for i in range(big_df.shape[0]):
    big_df['nb_trade']=5*(i+1)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why not `np.arange(5, 5*(big_df.shape[0]+1), 5)`?

Comment: Thanks. However, doing this is not the result I wanted. I wanted to increment line by line within a single column. I used df['new'] = np.arange(5, df.shape[0] * 5 + 5, 5) instead.

Comment: Both are same, see the answer below!

Comment: I am sorry, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `range` or [`np.arrange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
print (df)
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

df['new'] = range(5, len(df.index) * 5 + 5, 5)
print (df)
   a  new
0  1    5
1  2   10
2  3   15
```

---

```
df['new'] = np.arange(5, df.shape[0] * 5 + 5, 5)
print (df)
   a  new
0  1    5
1  2   10
2  3   15
```

Solution of `John Galt` from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168494/python-pandas-dataframe-iteration-through-a-column#comment79298996_46168494):

```
df['new'] = np.arange(5, 5*(df.shape[0]+1), 5)
print (df)
   a  new
0  1    5
1  2   10
2  3   15
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael. Thnk you, the arange method worked. The range method did not match the number of rows originally.